# Excel SUMIFS function with numbers saved as text

Tags: excel, sumifs, sumproduct

SUMIFS with numbers saved in text format (column A) is not producing the correct result.

As you can see in the sample code below, cell F3 is producing the correct result when both referenced column (column B) and referencing cell (cell E3) are both in numeric format. However, when referenced column (column A) and referencing cell (Cell E4) are both in Text format, SUMIFS produces an incorrect result. I repeated the excise using all letter text(instead of Numeric formatted as Text), everything seems to be working fine as expected. (see row13 to row20)

After some googling, I found a walkaround using SUMPRODUCT instead of SUMIFS, unfortunately this walkaround doesn't work in my case, because I would like the referencing cell to be either with or without the "<>", like "<>127", "127", "D" or "<>D", which would only work with SUMIFS formula (sample cell F18).

I guess to summarize, can someone help me to get the formula in cell F8 to work using SUMFIS, OR to get formula in F20 to work using SUMPRODUCT.

thanks

[image: samples]

Comment: The only way to make the SUMIF work is to use already converted values (column B).  SUMPRODCUCT will not work because it is not set up to interpret text equations.  So if using already converted data is not an option then the best would be to write your own function that uses `Worksheet.Evaluate` to accept a string equation in the SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, unfortunately convert data back into numeric format isn't an option in my case. I will look into UDF option.